# Simple loop not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I am cutting info out of somewhere which gives me team names. If I do `echo $HomeTeam;`, I get the value "Man Utd".

But when I do this.. it doesn't work (shows blank).

```
$PlayerName = "Robin Van Persie"; //just to test that it's working
switch($PlayerName)
    {
    case "Robin Van Persie":
        if ($HomeTeam == "Man Utd") { echo $HomeTeam; } 
        break;
    default: echo "Player not in the list"; break;
    }
```

This shows as blank... Any ideas why? I tried adding `$HomeTeam = strval($HomeTeam);` to convert it to a string but didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try `var_dump($PlayerName,$HomeTeam)`. Make sure the string lengths are ***exactly*** what they should be.

Comment: and an 'else' to that 'if' that echos a message. I am thinking that the case is working but the 'if' is not.

Comment: BTW In a real world situation hard coding this is going to get large and unmaintainable, you would be better storing your data in a database, then you can simply forget this switch statement.

Comment: @Kolink - if I `echo $HomeTeam;`, I just get "Man Utd", but if I write what you posted I get a long list of stuff...   string(16) "Robin Van Persie" object(simple_html_dom_node)#1007 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(2) "td" ["attr"]=> array(1) { ["class"]=> string(11) "ismAwayTeam" } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#1008 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(3) ["tag"]=> string(4) "text" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(0) { } ["parent"]=> *RECURSION* ["_"]=> array(1) .... lots more...

Comment: @DawsonLoudon If I add an `Else`, it does whatever is in the Else part, but the problem is I'm looking for it to pick up the value in the `if`. Ultimately I want it to say IF home team is Man Utd then list what the away team is. I tried to simplify it for the sake of the question.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I agree. I will be putting this into a database as soon as I get it working simply first. I am only putting a few players in to confirm it's working, then I will worry about getting the DB set up. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: if(trim($HomeTeam) == "Man Utd")

Answer (score 0):

`$HomeTeam` variable is not set, that's why it returns empty when printed. set the value to something like this & it should work.

```
$PlayerName = "Robin Van Persie"; //just to test that it's working
$HomeTeam = "Man Utd";
switch($PlayerName)
    {
    case "Robin Van Persie":
        if ($HomeTeam == "Man Utd") { echo $HomeTeam; } //Man Utd
        break;
    default: echo "Player not in the list"; break;
    }
```

Comment: It does not return empty when printed. If I `echo $HomeTeam;` without the if loop it returns "Man Utd", but not if it's in the if loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have `if ($HomeTeam == "Man Utd")` nothing else is set to happen, so $HomeTeam must not equal `"Man Utd"`

Comment: well.. that's the thing.. When I echo it out (without if loop), it does show as "Man Utd" so I was thinking that it's not stored as a string or something.

Comment: yeah, that is probably it. Can you check if it equals "Man Utd" when converted to a string?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$PlayerName = "Robin Van Persie"; //just to test that it's working
switch($PlayerName){
    case "Robin Van Persie":
        $HomeTeam ?  print($HomeTeam) : print("HomeTeam is not set");
    break;
    default: echo "Player not in the list"; break;
}
```

Comment: This echoes out the value of $HomeTeam so it looks like it'll work. What does `$HomeTeam ? print($HomeTeam)` do though? I was going to have if loops to catch every team and I'm not sure how to make it work with the code you listed. Thanks.

Comment: @Cully `print` is nearly like `echo` function, and the `$HomeTeam ?  print($HomeTeam) : print("HomeTeam is not set");` is a short hand to check if the var equals to true, `$var ? #do something if true : #do something else if false`

Comment: @Cully how are you retrieving the teams/players list?

Comment: I am scraping it from somewhere using simple_html_dom. I am cutting out the values and I have code that loops 10 times (10 games per week, so once per game)... it then checks $HomeTeam and $AwayTeam and echoes both out. This works and just echoes $HomeTeam as "Man Utd", but there's obviously something mucking it up. I cut out that other stuff to simplify the question. Thanks for the loop short form. I'll see if I can figure this out a different way.

Comment: @Cully I just saw your `var_dump()` results, and the issue seems to be caused by the `$HomeTeam` being an object which is the call return from simple_html_dom probably, thats why you are able to echo it but not compare it, and in the code i posted for you it worked because i was checking if `$HomeTeam` equals to TRUE, try to convert  `$HomeTeam` into a string or get the specific value out of the object into a new string var

Answer (score 0):

If your going to hard code it and not store your values in a database perhaps this method of using an array will interest you:

```
$search = "Robin Van Persie";

//Your data array, easyier to add to no
$teams = array(
    'Manchester United'=>array('Robin Van Persie',
                               'Wayne Rooney',
                               ),

    'Arsenal'=>array('Theo Walcott',
                     'Nicklas Bendtner',
                     ),             
);

$result=null;
foreach($teams as $team=>$players) {
    if(in_array($search,$players)) {
        $result = $team;
    }
}
//Robin Van Persie's team is Manchester United
echo ($result != null) ? $search.'\'s team is '.$result : 'Team for '.htmlentities($search).' not found.';
```